# deserialize the XML Document --- Need Help

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, serialization, web-services

I am using the below code snippet now to deserialize the XML document ...

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlDocument OrderDocument(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
{
   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(sendOrder.Order));

   string xmlString = xmlDoc.OuterXml.ToString();

   byte[] buffer = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString);

   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);

   sendOrder.Order orderDoc = (sendOrder.Order)serializer.Deserialize(ms);

   sendOrder.WebService_ConsureWebService ws = 
         new sendOrder.WebService_ConsureWebService();

   ws.Operation_1(ref orderDoc);

   return xmlDoc;
}
```

Can anybody please tell what is wrong with the code, as the error says there is an error in the XML document but if you check the document I am passing and the even the Order object its got the same structure and the namespace

> There is an error in XML document (1,
>   2). --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException:
>   http://ConsureWebService.Order'>
>   was not expected.

Comment: please highlight your code sections in the editor, and then click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar, or press Ctrl-K on your keyboard, to format as code (and get syntax highlighting and all)

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in GetBytes(), what's the value of xmlString?

Comment: Can't you just use `Order` as argument to your web method?

Comment: Updated to reflect the comments (sample) you added; now works.

Comment: If you can't update the source (to include [XmlRoot]), I can show you how to customise the `XmlSerializer` instead; add a comment (to my reply) if that would be helpful.

Comment: Pleass do let me know how do I do it ... thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that it is a namespace issue (i.e. xml namespaces). Can you show example xml and the `Order` class?

For info, you can read from an `XmlDocument` "as is", via:

```
sendOrder.Order orderDoc;
using(XmlReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc.DocumentElement)) {
    orderDoc = (sendOrder.Order) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Much simpler than messing with encoding and streams...

---

With your sample xml/code, you can fix this by adding:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "ConsureWebService.Order")]
```

to the class. If the class advertises itself as a `partial class` you can even do this in a separate code file, so you don't need to edit the generated code. This would be (in the correct namespace):

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "ConsureWebService.Order")]   
public partial class Order { }
```

Comment: The XML document I am passing is as below

<ns0:Order xmlns:ns0="http://ConsureWebService.Order">
<OrderId>OrderId_0</OrderId>
<OrderName>OrderName_0</OrderName>
</ns0:Order>

Comment: Also, this is the sendOrder.Order object I am trying to deserialize to:

namespace sendOrder
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://ConsureWebService.Order")]
    [GeneratedCode("System.Xml", "2.0.50727.3053")]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    [DesignerCategory("code")]
    public class Order
    {
        public Order();

        public string OrderId { get; set; }
        public string OrderName { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(sendOrder.Order));
        sendOrder.Order orderDoc;
        using (XmlReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc.DocumentElement))
        {
            orderDoc = (sendOrder.Order)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);    
        }

using the above code snippet, while debugging I am getting null value for the reader thou, I can find xml document for the xmlDoc

Comment: The order file meta data file, I am trying to consume an exposed BTS webs ervice ..................................................................................................................................

namespace sendOrder
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://ConsureWebService.Order")]
    [GeneratedCode("System.Xml", "2.0.50727.3053")]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    [DesignerCategory("code")]
    public class Order
    {
        public Order();

        public string OrderId { get; set; }
        public string OrderName { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
<ns0:Order xmlns:ns0="ConsureWebService.Order">; 
      <OrderId>OrderId_0</OrderId> 
      <OrderName>OrderName_0</OrderName> 
 </ns0:Order>
```

This doesn't appear to be a fully valid xml document, can you post up the whole thing?  It is kind of like giving someone only the first line of a stack trace and saying "Well!" .

EDIT

Here is a guess: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816225

Do you have a default constructor?

Comment: NO this the complete XML document that I am passing and trying to deserialze to the sendOrder.Order object ... both I have posted as a comment earlier

Comment: And If you notice even the namespace and structure of the document is same ... I am clueless as to why the below error is coming ..



System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <Order xmlns='http://ConsureWebService.Order'> was not expected.

Comment: I am trying deserialize the sendOrder.Order Object which does have default constructur


namespace sendOrder { 

[Serializable] [XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "ConsureWebService.Order")] [GeneratedCode("System.Xml", "2.0.50727.3053")] [DebuggerStepThrough] [DesignerCategory("code")] 

public class Order { 

public Order(); 

public string OrderId { get; set; } 
public string OrderName { get; set; } 
} 
}